# Convert string to a vector of integers

Tags: c++, string, vector

I need to make a function in C++, which takes a string, which contains only digits, for example:

```
string s = "7654321"
```

and converts it to a vector of integers. So vector should be like this:

```
vec[1] = '7'
vec[2] = '6'
```

etc.

I tried to use isstringstream, but that was useless in this situation, cause that string has no spaces in it.

Comment: Hm, maybe you should write it yourself?

Comment: I tried to make it in a lot ways, but I was failed in all of them. I tried to use vec.push_back(atoi(str[i])); but it doesnt works. I want to find an easy way without writing bicycles. Thanx for your comprehensive and very useful comment.

Comment: the atoi should work almost, You need to make a substring of just that one character

Comment: the sarcasm about useful comment doesnt help. Its better to show that you tried something that felt reasonable and that didnt work. Many times people post things like this without ever trying anything, hence the first comment

Comment: or push_back str[i] - '0'

Comment: A lot of code pieces would make a question a little bit "dirty" and tough to read, so a small question became gigantic stuff which is really difficult to understand. Stackoverflow tells me to be more specific, and I tried to make a short & specific question. Furthermore I didn't store my unsuccessful code, so a lot of my tries was already deleted. Such a pity, that you downvote my question, cause it could be useful for many persons, I think. Unfairly.

Comment: well your question has now confused people, you want '7' or 7 in the integers? Two different things (that differ by '0' - which is why I said str[i] - '0')

Comment: i want 7, not '7' in the integers. thank you for you suggest with str[i] - '0'. It works good and btw I never heard about such way of type converting.

Comment: It works because '0' through '9' are a set of contiguous values in all character sets used in a valid C or C++ compiler. They are *not* actually the values 0 through 9. In ASCII, '0' has a value of 48, '1' of 49, etc. Subtracting the offset of '0' from the values of the digits produces how far they are from '0', which due to the contiguity of digits, will be value of the digit they represent. They're converted to `int` in the arithmetic operation because `-` takes `int` arguments at the smallest--smaller arguments are converted to int. You can look at '5' - '0' as `(int)53 - (int)48 = (int)5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop to iterate through the string, and fill the vector with each value using push_back() and -'0'

assuming vector vec;

```
void fillVec(const string str1, vector<char> & vec) {

    for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++)
        vec.push_back(str1[i]) - '0';

}
```

Example program implementing this

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void fillVec(const string, vector<int> &); 

int main()
{
  vector<int> vec;
  string str1 = "1234567";
  fillVec(str1, vec);

    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    cout << vec[i] << ", ";

    return 0;


}

void fillVec(const string str1, vector<int> & vec) {

        for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++)
            vec.push_back(str1[i]-'0');

}
```

Comment: This will convert the character values to integers and store them, not the digits they display as. A '0' in the string would result in a value of 48 getting stored in the vector.

Comment: You are right. I have changed it and tested it, it should work now

Comment: Converting to `vector<char>` doesn't fix the problem

Comment: u didnt change anything in the code

Comment: Check now, apologies

Comment: convert the values to int before printing.

Comment: [look at what happens here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94d354b74baa027c) when you convert the values to int before printing. It *looks* like your solution works using the printing method in your answer, but only because you're printing individual characters, which are displayed with much the same logic as strings. When you convert them to integers as OP requests and then use the integer-appropriate printing method, it becomes plain that the vector is filled with incorrect values.

Comment: Incidentally, you probably want to enable warnings on your compiler--the warnings given by a compiler with a high warnings level are usually useful, frequently fix/prevent bugs, and always help enforce some level of style consistency.

Comment: Eh, I've been programming for 12 straight hours trying to finish a final assignment so I suppose that slipped my mind. I'm sure OP could use ASCII values (his string is only integers) to figure out a simple way to convert the values before storing them.

Comment: Thanks, Connor. I'll try to convert that char vector to integers before storing. It should be easier than string convert, I think. Thank you one more time.

Comment: I've done it for you now. Simply use -'0' to convert from char to int while preserving value

Comment: wow! incredible. I didn't knew it could be done in such way. how does it works?

Comment: When you use - '0', it's basically a shortcut to tell the compiler to return an integer instead of a character. Not too sure exactly how it works but it's a handy little tool. Would you mind selecting best answer if it worked?

Comment: Yep! Thank you. It was interesting.